# Hiding WSDL in JAX-WS

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws

I'm, using JAX-WS in order to build and deploy web-services.

Everything is working properly, however I need to hide the WSDL. In other words, If the user goes to the following URL: http://foo.com/wm-ws/WMService2?wsdl, i don't want the WSDL to show.

I read that we could use the @WSDL annotation so i did that as follows:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "WMService2",
        targetNamespace = "http://test.wmservice.soap/",
        portName = "WMService2")
@WSDL(exposed = false)

public class WMService2
{
  ...
}
```

But this doesn't change anything..The WSDL is still showing. I've seen work-around where a filter is created, but i think it's an overkill.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, your client will likely require the WSDL at runtime.  It is possible to get around this with hand-crafted client code or by including a local copy of the WSDL (which requires a bit of magic in an EE environment, namely packaging the WSDL in your artifact and specifying a wsdl-location in your wsimport (I can provide more info if desired; this is also a valid solution: [JAX-WS client : what's the correct path to access the local WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163586/jax-ws-client-whats-the-correct-path-to-access-the-local-wsdl)).  This explains more about the dependency but it's also a good idea to have it available for interoperability: [Why is WSDL required for Java Client at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712178/why-is-wsdl-required-for-java-client-at-runtime)

With that said, it sounds like what you're actually trying to accomplish is restrict access to web resources, which is easily accomplished with a web.xml.  Specifically you can add a security constraint,

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>*?wsdl</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**although this will mean that you must set up authentication in your container and authenticate in your client** (what is your container? client?).  The url-pattern can be anything and the role-name * indicates any authenticated user may access the resource.

About security contraints: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html

Comment: The only client using this web-service are internal products who are given the WSDL manually to develop against it. This won't be an exposed web service to be used by the public. I could use the filter as you said but then what's the purpose of this: @WSDL(exposed = false)