# Is wsdl used at runtime for actually making a connection

Tags: wsdl, webservices-client

After i have used wsdl to generate web service client classes, do i still need to use the wsdl at runtime?
It seems like i dont have to, but in the generated classes , I see a url link to the wsdl file. So is the wsdl needed at runtime for the client to consume the web services?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language. You didn't specify what you're using, but - for example...

- In c#, if you generate a proxy via Visual Studio, the WSDL is not
  used at runtime; it generates a class for you that is used instead.
- I have seen other clients that require a local copy of the WSDL;
  older versions of the MS Soap Toolkit required one. We ran into this
  when using that toolkit with VB6.
- According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712178/why-is-wsdl-required-for-java-client-at-runtime), java requires a wsdl at runtime
  because some dependencies are generated at runtime.