# Workday - How to programmatically get list of WSDLs in Workday

Tags: wsdl, workday-api

I am working on developing an integration with Workday. Under my initial analysis, I found that Workday provides multiple wsdls for different modules like "Human resource", "Inventory" etc. I can see this complete list at https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/operations/index.html

I am trying to understand how I get get this list progamatically in my integration so that my user can select one of the wsdls rather than typing in the full name of WSDL. Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 7):

You can programatically retrieve a list of all web service operations by creating a Custom Report based on the "Public Web Services" data source. The report can then be exposed as a RESTful WS for easy retrieval. 
Some fields you can include in the report are: Web service, supported operations, api version, endpoint url, WSDL url, etc, etc. 
This is highly customisable, in the sense that you can query the RESTful WS Report for specific versions, specific operations, etc, via Prompts / URL Params. 
The report-as-a-service, supports also a variety of output formats as well as its own WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a SOAP WSDL is to generate a client stub, i.e. a model that lets your client interact with objects exposed or consumed by the service provider. You don't interact with a WSDL at runtime - you interact with the stub. If you want to make multiple services available, you have to include each WSDL in your client application at compile time and generate their stubs. The services in a given API version do not change, so there isn't a reason to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the query asked, what we are trying to understand is that whether there an API call/request which we could hit to get the list of web services available to populate it on the UI to select from it.
For Example: In this link,  https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/index.html, we have Absence_Management, Academic_Advising, Academic_Foundation and so on and Now, if I want it to be displayed to the end user so that He can select the webservice to be used and accordingly we could download the WSDL as to work on it.

Comment: Again, you do not use the WSDL at runtime (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904653/is-wsdl-used-at-runtime-for-actually-making-a-connection). You decide at build time which services you use, and therefore you know which services the user can interact with. You can display this list because the application knows what entries are in it.